# RhinoMocks equivalent of Return.CloneOf in NMock

Tags: unit-testing, rhino-mocks

We have a NextInterestDate property on a rhinomock that we initially set to 31/03/2000. This property is accessed and this date is used in the processing of interest calculations for March. Once the March processing is complete the property needs to be updated to be the next chronological interest date which is 30/04/2000.

The next time around the loop we want the mock to return the April end date when the NextInterestDate is accessed on the mock. In short a new date is recalculated each time around the loop and the property on the mock is reassigned with the new date.

This means that the date on the mock must be updated each time around the loop.

What we are seeing however is that the date remains at 31/03/2000 rather than be updated correctly.

We are relatively new to RhinoMocks but we much prefer it to NMocks, albeit there seems to be a steep learning curve.

To solve this problem the previous developer used NMock and used a clonable class that she utilised NMocks ...Return.CloneOF which allowed the mock to be able to update the mock and supply the new value.

We just can't seem to figure out the correct syntax / or a way to achieve this.

Many thanks in advance Regards Colin

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that with `.WhenCalled` method. This might seem dodgy, but does exactly the thing you want to:

```
var expectedDates = new[]
{
    new DateTime(2000, 3, 31),
    new DateTime(2000, 4, 30),
    new DateTime(2000, 5, 31),
};

var invocationsCount = 0;
service.Expect(s => s.NextInterestDate)
    .WhenCalled(m => m.ReturnValue = expectedDates[invocationNumber++])
    .Return(default(DateTime));
```

What code above does is simply takes next element from `expectedDates` array with each successive invocation. The strange call to `Return(default(DateTime))` at the end must be there (otherwise Rhino will complain). You shouldn't worry tho - fake return value **is ignored** when we already specify one with `WhenCalled`.

Note that you need to be careful with code like one above (*incrementing counters, arrays* - all that in mock setup). Readability is not the greatest, so having proper variables/test method naming is crucial.

Comment: Good answer. However, since those new dates are calculated I'd put the calculation algorithm into the WhenCalled block instead of taking static ones from the array (if possible, of course).

Comment: @IvanGerken: if dates indeed come from algorithm, algorithm should be *stubbed* and fed with prepared values. Otherwise, one day somebody might change algorithm and bunch of unrelated tests suddenly break. You don't want any kind of *nondeterminism* in unit test.